# Finding the average of parameters controlled by other indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, average

I need some help in this problem

I have this matrix in MATLAB:

```
A = [ 25    1.2    1
      28    1.2    2
      17    2.6    1
      18    2.6    2
      23    1.2    1
      29    1.2    2
      19    15     1
      22    15     2
      24    2.6    1
      26    2.6    2];
```

1st column is some measured values for temperature

2nd column is an index code representing the color (1.2:red,.....etc)

3rd column is the hour of taking the sample. Only at hours from 1 to 2

I want the matrix to be controlled by 2nd column as follows:

if it is 1.2, the program will find the average of all temperatures at hour 1 that

corresponds to 1.2

So, here ( 25 + 23 )/2 = 24

and also finds the average of all temperatures at hour 2 and that corresponds

to 1.2, ( 28 + 29 ) /2 = 28.5

and this average values:

```
                     [24 
                      28.5]
```

will replace all temperature values at hours 1 and 2

that corresponds to 1.2 .

Then, it does the same thing for indices 2.6 and 15

So, the desired output will be:

```
B = [  24
       28.5

       15.5
       22

       24
       28.5

       19
       22

       15.5
       22]
```

My problem is in using the loop. I could do it for only one index at one run.

for example,

```
T=[];
   index=1.2;

   for i=1:length(A)
       if A(i,2)==index
        T=[T A(i,1)];
    else
        T=[T 0];
       end
   end
```

So, T is the extracted T that corresponds to 1.2 and other entries are zeros

Then, I wrote long code to find the average and at the end I could find the matrix

that corresponds to ONLY the index 1.2 :

```
B =   [24
       28.5

       0
       0

       24
       28.5

       0
       0

       0
       0]
```

But this is only for one index and it assigns zeros for the other indices. I can do this for all

indices in separate runs and then add the B's but this will take very long time since my real

matrix is 8760 by 5 .

I am sure that there is a shorter way to do that.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
B = zeros(size(A, 1), 1);
C = unique(A(:, 2))';
T = [1 2];

for c = C,
  for t = T,
      I1 = find((A(:, 2) == c) & (A(:, 3) == t));
      B(I1) = mean(A(I1, 1));
  end
end
```

**Edit**
I think your expected answer is wrong for `c = 2.6` and `t = 1`... Shouldn't it be `(17 + 24)/2 = 20.5`?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for this help.BTW, How can I learn like this codings and logical indexing ? I have some medium background in Matlab. Your code is time and effort saving.I wrote long if and for loops to trying to get the answer.Thanks. Sorry. I calculated 17 + 24 = 30. You are right.

Comment: You're welcome :)  I can't think of any specific learning material for logical indexing other than experience (technically this isn't logical indexing, but the idea is the same).  Take this as an example and try to understand what's going on, then next time you need it maybe it will come in handy :)  If you don't understand any of it, I'd be glad to try to explain.

Comment: You don't need to use find for this.  The following should give the same result:
      match = (A(:, 2) == c) & (A(:, 3) == t);
      B(match) = mean(A(match, 1));

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, perhaps more neatly, with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[~, ~, ii] = unique(A(:,2)); %// indices corresponding to second col values
ind = [ii A(:,3)]; %// build 2D-indices for accumarray
averages = accumarray(ind, A(:,1), [], @mean); %// desired averages of first col
result = averages(sub2ind(max(ind), ind(:,1), ind(:,2))); %// repeat averages
```