# Take average of only part of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix

This is a very simple question to be asking, so bear with me please.

[Possible Duplicate?] [Finding the average of parameters controlled by other indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650037/finding-the-average-of-parameters-controlled-by-other-indices)

Say I have a matrix with data organized as follows

```
1 0.64
1 4.64
1 4.75
2 0.64
2 9.75
2 5.74
3 5.23
3 2.65
3 1.08
3 1.08
3 6.22
```

Now, I would like to take the average of those fields where the data is the same in the first column, like

```
1 3.34
2 5.37
3 3.25
```

Note that the size a particular set of values may vary, like `1` is repeated 3 times but `3` is repeated 5 times.
I have the maximum value of the first column in a variable called `figNum`, which for instance is `14`. The only problem is that I do not know the size of each dataset within the matrix.

Here are my efforts so far:

```
for p = 1:numel(matrix_name)
    if(matrix_name(p:1) == figNum)
       avg = avg + matrix_name(p:1);
    end
    figNum = figNum-1;
end
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: I think it may be a duplicate. Have you tried the code of the other post?

Comment: I tried, but couldn't apply it to my case. A better explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd go with a 1-liner first from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474519/split-matrix-based-on-number-in-first-column)

```
M = [1, 0.64;
     1, 4.64;
     1, 4.75;
     2, 0.64; 
     2, 9.75;
     2, 5.74;
     3, 5.23;
     3, 2.65;
     3, 1.08;
     3, 1.08;
     3, 6.22]

% This gives a cell array with 3 cells 
A = arrayfun(@(x) M(M(:,1) == x, :), unique(M(:,1)), 'uniformoutput', false)

% This gives a cell array with the means
c = cellfun(@mean, A, 'UniformOutput', false)

% Convert back to matrix
cell2mat(c)
```

Comment: I have an issue with this solution now.
Suppose my array `M` has 46 entries in the first column, and the corresponding values are 0, then the final matrix after `cell2mat(c)` is having only 42 entries. I think the `unique()` part is causing problems with the final answer.

For example:
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`
`4    0`

Comment: Didn't quite get what the problem is - Could you post the M causing the trouble? Your example worked okay in my matlab (returned a matrix [4, 0])

Comment: I guess it was an issue with something else. It's working fine enough now.
I was trying to access a value out of bounds for some reason.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from this [sweet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22765170/3293881) -

**Code**

```
%// Assuming A is your input matrix

A =[1 0.64
    1 4.64
    1 4.75
    2 0.64
    2 9.75
    2 5.74
    3 5.23
    3 2.65
    3 1.08
    3 1.08
    3 6.22]

[~,~,ind] = unique(A(:,1))
average_values = accumarray(ind, A(:,2), [], @mean)
```

Now, if first column is `A` always sorted you can use -

```
average_values = nonzeros(accumarray(A(:,1), A(:,2), [], @mean))
```

Alongwith being sorted, if the first column has values in consecutive order as is the case with the given data, you can use a very simple code -

```
average_values = accumarray(A(:,1), A(:,2), [], @mean)
```

**Output**

```
average_values =
    3.3433
    5.3767
    3.2520
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call you matrix `A`, you can use this code to do what you want:

```
% find diferent indexes
ind=unique(A(:,1));
avrg=zeros(numel(ind),1);

for ii=1:numel(ind)
%     In case your index are not in ascending order +1
      auxind=ind(ii);
%       compute the mean of the 2column in the indexes that are equal to
%       actual index
      avrg(ii)=mean(A(find(A(:,1)==auxind),2));


end
```